# Opening the code generated from CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cmake, assimp

I am trying to build Assimp to use in visual studio 2012.

Following the instructions on their website: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/cmake_build.htm I have tried to build assimp,  however I am stuck on the last step "Open the generated solution/project files and have fun"

This is the build folder which was created by CMake - http://puu.sh/fq8kp/cc16e985c3.png

Following the advice of another tutorial I opened this in the terminal and tried to type "make" and launch it. However there isnt a make file so this didnt work. I also typed "install" as there is an install file, however this also did not work.

The tutorial goes as follows:

- Type "make" and launch it; you should see the build progressing without issues
- When the build is finished, type "sudo make install"; it will ask for your password and install the library!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'generated solution/project' in your case (windows) would be the Assimp.sln file. You generated a visual studio solution, so you have to use Visual Studio to build the application.

According to your screenshot, the Assimp.sln file is the 9 KB sized file underneath the one with size 45,120 KB